# openpyxl keep formula cells as percentages

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet that has some cells with formulas. In those cells are percent values like `19.6%`. I'm using python to load the workbook with `"data_only = True"` because I'm copying the numbers in these cells.

When I do this I'm getting `19.6%` returned as `0.19615003`. Is there a way I can load the workbook and keep that `19.6%`? Or convert all cells with decimals to percentages with the percent sign?

I tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
Sheet["A3"].number_format = Format_percentage_0
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you are trying to do. If nothing else, then please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: The cells contain 0.1961.  That's their value.  Excel happens to show you 19.6% because the display format for that cell is set to `%`.  If you want it displayed that way, then you need to format it yourself.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. I hard coded it for each cell that had it. It looks messy but it works.